# Exibir porcentagem no PHP

Tags: php

Preciso exibir uma porcentagem assim `0,75` mas está exibindo assim: `0,00`

segue meu código:

```
<?php 
echo number_format((float)$array['JUROS'], 2, ',', '.'); 
?>
```

O valor que vem do banco é `0,75`

Obrigado.

Comment: O separador decimal no PHP é o ponto, então ele só entenderá se for `0.75`, ou seja, você precisará primeiro substituir a vírgula por ponto antes de formatar.

Comment: Ok, deu certo. Obrigado!